# SQL - How do split data by date into different monthly 'pots'?

Tags: sql

New to sql and having trouble figuring the following, though probably straightforward for more experienced users. I have a table of outstanding monies which I need to divide up into monthly pots; the table has the following columns:

```
Name, amount_due, date_due.
```

I need to divide the info by 'date_due' into 5 different monthly pots, the current month, last month, 2 months old, 3 months old, > 3 months old.

Comment: Which database are you using? Sql-Server, MySql?

Comment: Are you wanting the rows "grouped" such that they're actually *sorted* into contiguous rows with the same "pot" value - or aggregate/summary data for each pot instead?

Comment: Many thanks for your swift response. The rows would need to be grouped by name, so one distinct row per name with columns for the total current month outstanding, 1 month old outstanding etc. Hope this helps. Many thanks.

Comment: @Coopernicus You did not mention the name requirement in your posting. Please provide sample source data and an example of how you want the final output to look.

Comment: Hi, using Oracle, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're after summary data that performs a `SUM` for each month, as opposed to showing all the rows sorted by month.

```
name   , amount_due, date_due
Alice  ,        100, 2017-09-10
Bob    ,        500, 2017-07-03
Charlie,        300, 2017-07-02
Dan    ,        150, 2017-04-01
Eve    ,        200, 2017-01-01
Faith  ,         50, 2017-09-13
```

This query converts the `date_due` value into a "month" value (while still retaining `date` or `datetime` type information), then sums them by each month:

Output:

```
sum_amount_due, month_due
           150, 2017-09-01
           800, 2017-07-01
           150, 2017-04-01
           200, 2017-01-01
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    SUM( amount_due ) AS sum_amount_due,
    DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 ) AS month_due
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 )
ORDER BY
    month_due
```

This query does not handle dates older than 3 months specially, so for that we need to change the `month_due` expression to return `'2001-01-01'` for dates older than 3 months:

Output:

```
sum_amount_due, month_due
           150, 2017-09-01
           800, 2017-07-01
           350, 2000-01-01
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    SUM( amount_due ) AS sum_amount_due,
    CASE
        WHEN date_due < DATEADD( month, GETDATE(), -3 ) THEN '2000-01-01'
        ELSE DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 )
    END AS month_due
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN date_due < DATEADD( month, GETDATE(), -3 ) THEN '2000-01-01'
        ELSE DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 )
    END
ORDER BY
    month_due
```

Due to how SQL works, you need to repeat the get-month expression in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

This can be made slightly syntactically simpler by using a subquery to identify records older than 3 months:

```
SELECT
    SUM( amount_due ) AS sum_amount_due,
    CASE
        WHEN month_due_3_months THEN '2000-01-01'
        ELSE month_due
    END AS month_due
FROM
(
    SELECT
        amount_due,
        DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 ) AS month_due,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, date_due ), 0 ) < DATEADD( month, GETDATE(), -3 ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS month_due_3_months
    FROM
        your_table
) AS all_months
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN month_due_3_months THEN '2000-01-01'
        ELSE month_due
    END AS month_due
ORDER BY
    month_due
```

The syntactic complexity is due to some constraints inherent in the SQL language:

- The `SELECT` sub-clause ("the projection") is evaluated *after* the `FROM` AND `GROUP BY` sub-clauses, so you cannot reference aliased expressions in `GROUP BY`: you must either repeat them or specify them in a subquery.
- SQL does not have a `Get month as date value` function, surprisingly, you must use `DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF( month, 0, @dateValue ), 0 )`.

  - Do not use `GETMONTH` or `DATEPART` because it returns only the month component and disregards the year value, so it will incorrectly group rows from different years that share the same month.
- There is no ternary operator in SQL, only the more verbose `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END` construct (though there is `COALESCE`, `NULLIF`, and `ISNULL` but those are special-cases).

Answer (score 1):

I assumed all periods are cumulative, if not you need to modify each condition. Let me know if this works as expected or need modification.

```
select name 
    ,sum( case when datediff(day,getdate(),date_due)<day(date_due) then amount_due end) 'current month'
    ,sum( case when datediff(month,getdate(),date_due)<=1 then amount_due end) 'last month'
    ,sum( case when datediff(month,getdate(),date_due)<=2 then amount_due end) 'last two month'
    ,sum( case when datediff(month,getdate(),date_due)<=3 then amount_due end) 'last three month'
    ,sum( case when datediff(month,getdate(),date_due)>3 then amount_due end) 'more than three month'
from monies
group by name
```

Comment: @Coopernicus Take into consideration 3 months debt includes 2 months debt and so on. If you need to identify as 3-month debt only debt between month 2 and 3, we need to subtract previous period amount. It is simple, let me know.

Comment: @coopernicus why unaccept this answer? Igual thougt it helpd you atte they time

Answer (score 0):

Use case to determine the due_date between months of due

```
SELECT name,
       amount_due,
       due_date,
       CASE WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm, 0, GETDATE())
            THEN 'this month'
            WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
            THEN 'last month'
            WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE())
            THEN '2 months old'
            WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())
            THEN '3 months old'
            WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATETIME) < DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE())
            THEN '> 3 months old'
        END month_of_due
```